# Receiving zmq message with error every one hour

Tags: python, zeromq, reactor

I should say, that before I've started to use zmq reactor instead of poller everything worked fine.

```
class BaseZmqReceiver(BaseZmqNode):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, host, port, hwm, bind, on_receive_callback):
        super(BaseZmqReceiver, self).__init__(host=host, port=port, bind=bind, hwm=hwm)
        self.node.on_message_callback = on_receive_callback
        self.stream = ZMQStream(self.socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.on_message_received)
        ZmqLoopRunner().start()

    def on_message_received(self, message):
        return self.node.on_message_callback(message)

    def create_node(self):
        return ReceivingNode(None, None)

class ZmqLoopRunner(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ZmqLoopRunner, self).__init__()
        self.loop = IOLoop.instance()
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        self.loop.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.loop.stop()


class ZmqSubscriber(BaseZmqReceiver):
    def __init__(self, host, port, on_receive_callback, bind=False, hwm=1000):
        super(ZmqSubscriber, self).__init__(host=host, port=port, hwm=hwm, bind=bind,
                                            on_receive_callback=on_receive_callback)

    def create_socket(self):
        socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
        return socket
```

Here is my zmq code.

And I'm basically just receiving multipart message in callback.

```
def on_message(message):
    part1, part2 = message
```

And every one hour I've got message that consist of only one part. So I got

```
TypeError: need more than one value to unpack.
```

EDIT here is my full zmq code.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7jQezPDaLZFQWxBMUdXQkxnS1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `part1, part2 = message` will try to unpack message. Is that a list ? Are you sure it contains 2 parts ?

Comment: In zmqloop on_recv every message us multipart. My code is works most of the time. It wotks in tests. Everything was working with poller and with reactor every hour one message have one part instead of two.

Comment: I would suggest writing some data out to a file, and then editing your original post to contain that data. @Depado already asked you if you are sure the message contains two parts. What would we need to run this? What would we need to install on our local systems, if we wanted to try this out?

Comment: For me the error definitely comes from that line, because there doesn't seem to be any other part of your code where you unpack values. It looks like you don't receive a "message" but a python error directly (is that what you want ? I have no knowledge of zmq)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't run this on your system. I just thought that there is some obvious (for zmq experts) mistake with zmq loop.

Comment: It is not a common issue. The odds are that a multipart message is not actually being sent. Can you provide sample code from the sending side that reproduces the issue? If nothing else, log the message that has incorrect form.

Comment: I've already logged it, it has exactly one full part of message, but not the other.
Also, the sending side is working perfectly with poller.

Comment: Can you show the sending side? What version of pyzmq and libzmq are you using? Can you also show the Poller implementation that works?

Comment: Um... I can't show you production code, but it just basic poller like in their examples.

  while True:
            try:
                socks = dict(self.zmq_poller.poll(50))
                if self.sock_stage0_input in socks and socks[self.sock_stage0_input] == zmq.POLLIN:

etc.
I'm using pyzmq 14 and libzmq 4.0>